# Changing the functionality of key in android

Tags: android, android-button

I have developed an android application in which some "OK" button (soft key) is present in the layout and it is used to handle some event .I want to map its functionality to hard key(like home key ) in my mobile during application run. I also want to know how to differentiate between single click and double click on an button. How to know the time gap between two button clicks and can we change that time period to handle double click.

Comment: what do u mean by hard keys? home button or back button?

Comment: yaa say home button,how can i assign some functionality to it

Comment: you mean you want to handle Home,Back buttons?

Comment: yaa i want to assign functionality to them to use,for some confirmation events like yes or no . if possible only single button with single click indicating yes and double click indicating no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not intercept the functionality of home button. as it is the only way that the user can come out of the app at any stage. You can override this function to intercept the functionality of `back button`:

```
 public void onBackPressed{
//do something here
}
```

EDIT:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: this method is related to backbutton??

Comment: yeah. but i dont think its appropriate if you use it for ur functionality. because back button is to go back to previous activity. and you said that want to take input from the user (yes or no). You can do that but i suggest you not to do that

Comment: instead you can add an alert dialog with yes and no.

Comment: no man i have to use the hard keys, because i am developing the app for blind.so tell me how to override the functionality of both of them and how to differentiate between single and double clicks

Comment: see my edit. You can override this functions. Instead of double click, Long click..

Comment: for back button keycode is KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK and for home button its KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME

Comment: what is the difference between normal click and long click (how the time is taken into consideration).cant we handle the double click.  and public void onBackPressed {} is for back button then what method should be overrided for home button

Comment: i donno whether it can be handled or not, but generally only click and longclick are used

Comment: what method should be overrided for home button? : See my edit you can override onKeyDown

Comment: so keydown and longkey press are used to simulate the buttons with the keycodes KEYCODE_BACK and KEYCODE_HOME. i got it. what is the purpose of  public void onBackPressed{
//do something here
}
in ur answer , what it will do?

Comment: its similar to onKeyDown with KEYCODE_BACK

Comment: but there is one more method onKeyUp.

Comment: so if u want a function to be done while  pressing down the key, its onKeyDown, If its a function to be done while removing the finger from the key, its onKeyUp. But if u want a function like onKeyPress, its onBackPressed

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){

            finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent(URCLASSNAME.this,Homeclassname.class));


        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

In android you cant override home button hence whatever you want to do, do it when back key is pressed.